# Acquiring location when app is close like WeBuyApp.com claim to do in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

It's just brought to my attention today the guys at `www.webuyapp.com` which they claim to develop a patent-able algorithm to obtain location using push notification system even if the app is closed.

Personally I don't think it's possible as they claim:
http://www.webuyapp.com/?page_id=29

> How does it look on the customer side? All he has to do is download
>   WeBuy’s app. Once he has the app installed, we know at all times where
>   he is without draining his battery - via patentable algorithm we have
>   created. We know at all times what discounts surround him. Via complex
>   data mining, we know what our customer (personally) likes, and when we
>   feel we have a value proposition for him, we reach out and update him
>   via push notification. The push notification system itself has a
>   complexed data mining system which learns the users’ behavior to the
>   push and decides whether it’s a good idea to send a push or not.

Is there any real patent for obtaining location in background when app is closed using apple push notification?

Comment: just query a patent database and find out if a patent exists. Usually people knowing won't just answer and give all the information needed to do the same... from a technical point of view I see one or two solutions. from a privacy point of view it is horrible.

Comment: I think they're smart guessing location when GPS is closed. Rather then that I really don't know if there is an acceptable idea which Apple approve. Can you enlighten my eyes please?

Comment: Webuy doesn't claim they can get your location when the app is closed.  They just say when the user download the app. When the user download the app, they will run it and most likely it will be left in the background running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, the push notification is not used to obtain the location, it sounds like. CoreLocation allows you to keep monitoring the user's location even when the app in in the background. And with that data they are able to use their algorithm to make all of those decisions.